# Create a copy of the default Kubernetes Endpoint

Tags: kubernetes, service, endpoint, kube-proxy

I want to create a copy of the Default Kubernetes Endpoint associated with the default Kubernetes SVC. I also want to have the same list of `subsets.addresses` as the default Endpoint.

In order to achieve that I created a controller that watches the Nodes and when a node goes down/up, it updates my Endpoint resource.

What I see is that the default Endpoint resource is updated much faster than the Node resource and that causes my Endpoint resource to be a bit slower which causes downtime.

Can you suggest to me how can I make these changes with the speed of the default Endpoint changes? Maybe I can watch for changes directly on the default Endpoint in my controller?

Do you have other suggestions?